# Ember-Data models should save ids of non-Ember-Data-Models - how?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model which should save the ids of a client-side known model as an array to the server, but I'm struggling to find a good way to achieve this.

Here is the model class that is known by the client side and thus should *not* be synced with the server:

```
App.Browser = Em.Object.extend
  name: ''
  id: 0

App.Browser.reopenClass
  all: [
    UI.Browser.create(id: 1, name: 'Firefox')
    UI.Browser.create(id: 2, name: 'Chrome')
  ]

  find: (id) ->
    if arguments.length == 0
      return @all
    else
      @all.find((item) -> item.get('id') == id)
```

The model that syncs to the server looks like this:

```
App.Thingie = DS.Model.extend
  browserIds: DS.hasMany 'UI.Browser' # <-- this does not work, of course
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Write a custom Ember Data serializer with registerTransform, which maps to the object id of each object that needs to be saved and saves the resulting array. This works for creating objects, but the deserialize step just does not work, because you don't know which object to map the ids to during deserialization (the information is just not available there). Example see [1].
2. Try to hack ember-data to accept associations with non-ember-data models, but no luck.

The next thing I was going to try was going to try was creating a virtual array attribute for associating the browser objects, plus an observer that saves their ids to the array that syncs to the api. This will have to work 2-way, as loaded Thingie-Objects should have the associated objects available when they are loaded from the api (not just the ids).

But, maybe there is a simpler approach to achieve what I'm doing? Your help is greatly appreciated.

[1]
In the model:

```
DS.attr 'recordArray', { defaultValue: [] }
```

In the adapter:

```
DS.MyAdapter.registerTransform('recordArray',
  deserialize: (serialized) ->
    console.log('this does not work', serialized)
  serialize: (deserialized) ->
    deserialized.map((item) -> item.get('id'))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The next thing I was going to try was going to try was creating a virtual array attribute for associating the browser objects, plus an observer that saves their ids to the array that syncs to the api. This will have to work 2-way, as loaded Thingie-Objects should have the associated objects available when they are loaded from the api (not just the ids).

That approach will work. Assuming your adapter will serialize `browserIds` to/from an array of integers, just define `browserIds` as a computed property in your model. Something like:

```
App.Thingie = DS.Model.extend({
  browserIds: function(key, value) {
    // getter
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
      return this.get('browsers').getEach('id');
    // setter
    } else {
      return value.map( function(id) {
        App.Browser.find(id);
      });
    }
  }.property('browsers')
})
```

> But, maybe there is a simpler approach to achieve what I'm doing?

Yes I think what you are looking for is (enumerated transforms)[https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L575-L605]. Something like this should work:

```
DS.MyAdapter.registerEnumTransform('browsers', App.Browser.all);
App.Thingie = DS.Model.extend({
  browsers: DS.hasMany 'browsers'
})
```

One thing to keep in mind here is that the transform expects id to be index into the object array. It will totally ignore the `id` property of your UI.Browser objects.

Also see (enumerated transforms test)[https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/transform_test.js#L133-L169]

Comment: Thanks, this will help me greatly. Unfortunately, the ids I have to cope with are not sequential, but I think I can "trick" them to have the right indices when I pass the array to registerEnumTransform.

Comment: Yeah that should be possible. it might make sense for the transform to support id lookup, will give that some thought...